Quarkus JBeret: Is there a way to obtain the JobContext after the job finished?
I'm writing some integration tests for our Quarkus JBeret application and I'm trying to get the transientData from the JobContext to check the values stored in there.
Any idea if this is possible ?
I'm starting the job using something like this in my test:
   private JobExecutionImpl startJob(String jobXml, Properties jobParams) {
        try {
            this.jobLock.lock();
            long jobExecutionId = this.jobOperator.start(jobXml, jobParams);
            return (JobExecutionImpl) this.jobOperator.getJobExecution(jobExecutionId);
        } finally {
            this.jobLock.unlock();
        }
    }

so I have access to the JobExecution, but I cannot find a way to obtain the JobContext.

A batch job context holds the contextual data for a job execution. It is available within the scope of a job execution, and is not available outside, e.g., in the client.
You can inject a job context into any of the batch artifacts like ItemReader, ItemProcessor, ItemWriter, batch listeners, etc.
